# Exporting Cloudwatch logs in original format

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am looking to find a way to export CW logs in their original form to s3.  I used the console to export a days worth of logs from a log group, and it seems that a timestamp was prepended on each line, breaking the original JSON formatting.  I was looking to import this into glue as a json file for a test transformation script.  The original data used is formated as a normal json string when imported to cloudwatch and normally process the data it looks like:

```
{ "a": 123, "b": "456", "c": 789 }
```

After exporting and decompressing the data it looks like

```
2019-06-28T00:00:00.099Z { "a": 123, "b": "456", "c": 789 }
```

Which breaks reading the line as a json string since its no long a standard format.

The dataset is fairly large(100GB+) for this run, and will possibly grow larger in the future, so running the command a CLI command and processing each line locally isn't feasible in my opinion.  Is there any known way to do what I am looking to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeStamps are automatically added when you push the logs to the CloudWatch.
All the log events present in the CloudWatch has timestamp.

You can create a subscription filter to Kinesis Firehose and on Kinesis using lambda function you can formate the log events(remove the timestamp) then store the logs in the S3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html